# Issue with running a shell script without using 'sh' on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, shell, script, shell-script, zsh

I'm new to shell scripting and generally the usage of Terminal.
I recently made a `script.sh` that I want to use by just typing its name without the full path.
So, I wrote the path of the directory into `.zprofile` as:

```
export "PATH=$PATH:/path/to/scriptdirectory"
```

and changed the file permissions with:

```
% chmod +x script.sh
```

If I use the script with:

```
% sh myscript.sh
```

everything run smoothly as intended.
But if I try to omit the `sh` and type:

```
% myscript.sh
```

the script start running its first part, which is just reading a variable, but as soon as I insert the value, the follow line pops:

```
/path/to/scriptdirectory/script.sh:11: = not found
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "Do you want to set or change the backup location? (type y/n)"
read SET_BACKUP
while [ "$SET_BACKUP" != "y" ] && [ "$SET_BACKUP" != "n" ]
do
    echo "Please, write y or n:"
    read SET_BACKUP
done
if [ "$SET_BACKUP" == "y" ]
then
    echo "Write the absolute path of the desired backup location:"
    read BACKUP_FOLDER
    echo "Starting backup..."
    cp -R "/fileslocation" "$BACKUP_FOLDER"
    echo "Backup completed."
else
    echo "Starting backup..."
    cp -R "/fileslocation" "$BACKUP_FOLDER"
    echo "Backup completed."
fi
```

Comment: "At line 11 there's [...], so I think it's referring to that." -- What can we tell without seeing the script? Please [edit] the question and post the script, or at least a fragment near the line where the problem seems to be.

Comment: In addition to what @KamilMaciorowski says, you make no mention of your [shebang](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/10/on-the-shebang/) so we (and possibly you) have NO WAY to know what shell is interpreting your script.  When you did `sh thingy.sh` it implies that `sh` (the bourne shell) is executing your script and not `bash` or `zsh`.  Without it (and no shebang) you are using the system default (probably bash).  These behave differently.

Comment: I just edited the question and posted the whole script, thank you for the patience.
I used ```#!/bin/zsh``` as shebang.

Comment: What happens when you run it like `zsh script.sh`? Do you get the same error? Which line emits the error? I don't see a `=` around the 11th line

Comment: @glennjackman Everything's fine, the answer below is what I needed, thank you anyway. I have to use "[[" instead of "[" for zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that you're running the script with two different shell interpreters.

When you use `sh myscript.sh`, you're running `/bin/sh` and *not zsh*. When `sh` runs it reads your script `myscript.sh` and uses sh/bash shell rules for its syntax.

When you use just `myscript.sh`, the command used to run the script is determined by the first line: `#!/bin/zsh` (also known as the shebang). So it's run using `zsh` and uses its rules for syntax.

I see two solutions to get this working:

1. change the first line to use bash instead, so it'd be `#!/bin/bash`
2. read more about how conditionals work in zsh and fix the line that's broken (it looks like it's the line with `if [ "$SET_BACKUP" == "y" ]`)

Comment: Thank you so much, I just found about the issue with using "==" in zsh! Now everything goes as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, more of a formatted question.

3 things come to mind:

1. variable assignments must not have spaces around the `=`: `answer=42`
2. `$` is only used to ***de***-reference a variable, not to assign: don't do `$answer=42`
3. quote your variables: `if [ "$answer" = 42 ]`

This is me trying to read your mind. Put some code in your question.

Also, use https://shellcheck.net to validate your shell code.

Comment: I just posted the whole script on the question, sorry for that.
Spellcheck didn't find any issues, and I've already done all that you've suggested; also the script run completely fine if I use ```sh```.